# Jquery changing hrefs dynamically: $("a").each only hitting first link on page

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink, href, each

I have a page where part of the page is loaded from another source. In this partial, I have a number of links. However, the hrefs of the links need to be changed. I'm trying to use .each to change all of the link hrefs, but only the first link on the page gets changed.

```
$("a").each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    prop('href', ('http://nehgs/mvc' + url));
});
```

The alert box only pops up once. The first link does get changed correctly.

Comment: Check your console, you'll see an error. There will be the word `function` and `undefined` in it, I guarantee it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `prop` correctly. Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

You are close though, here is my solution:

```
$("a").each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
    var url = $(this).attr("href"); 
    $(this).prop('href', 'http://nehgs/mvc' + url);
});
```